# How to speed quicksort with numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to implement the quicksort algorithm using numba in Python.

It appears to be a lot slower than the numpy sort function.

How could I improve it? My code is here:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.autojit
def quick_sort(list_):
    """
    Iterative version of quick sort
    """
    #temp_stack = []
    #temp_stack.append((left,right))

    max_depth = 1000

    left = 0
    right = list_.shape[0]-1

    i_stack_pos = 0
    a_temp_stack = np.ndarray( ( max_depth, 2), dtype=np.int32 )
    a_temp_stack[i_stack_pos,0] = left
    a_temp_stack[i_stack_pos,1] = right
    i_stack_pos+=1
    #Main loop to pop and push items until stack is empty

    while i_stack_pos>0:

        i_stack_pos-=1
        right = a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 1 ]
        left  = a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 0 ]

        piv = partition(list_,left,right)
        #If items in the left of the pivot push them to the stack
        if piv-1 > left:
            #temp_stack.append((left,piv-1))

            a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 0 ] = left
            a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 1 ] = piv-1
            i_stack_pos+=1
        #If items in the right of the pivot push them to the stack
        if piv+1 < right:
            a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 0 ] = piv+1
            a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 1 ] = right
            i_stack_pos+=1

@nb.autojit( nopython=True )
def partition(list_, left, right):
    """
    Partition method
    """
    #Pivot first element in the array
    piv = list_[left]
    i = left + 1
    j = right

    while 1:
        while i <= j  and list_[i] <= piv:
            i +=1
        while j >= i and list_[j] >= piv:
            j -=1
        if j <= i:
            break
        #Exchange items
        list_[i], list_[j] = list_[j], list_[i]
    #Exchange pivot to the right position
    list_[left], list_[j] = list_[j], list_[left]
    return j
```

My test code is here:

```
    x = np.random.random_integers(0,1000,1000000)
    y = x.copy()

    quick_sort( y )

    z = np.sort(x)

    np.testing.assert_array_equal( z, y )

    y = x.copy()
    with Timer( 'nb' ):
        numba_fns.quick_sort( y )

    with Timer( 'np' ):
        x = np.sort(x)
```

UPDATE:

I have re-written the function to force the looping part of the code to run in nopython mode. The while loop does not appear to be causing nopython to fail. However, I have not gained any performance improvement:

```
@nb.autojit
def quick_sort2(list_):
    """
    Iterative version of quick sort
    """

    max_depth = 1000

    left        = 0
    right       = list_.shape[0]-1

    i_stack_pos = 0
    a_temp_stack = np.ndarray( ( max_depth, 2), dtype=np.int32 )
    a_temp_stack[i_stack_pos,0] = left
    a_temp_stack[i_stack_pos,1] = right
    i_stack_pos+=1
    #Main loop to pop and push items until stack is empty

    return _quick_sort2( list_, a_temp_stack, left, right )

@nb.autojit( nopython=True )
def _quick_sort2( list_, a_temp_stack, left, right ):

    i_stack_pos = 1
    while i_stack_pos>0:

        i_stack_pos-=1
        right = a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 1 ]
        left  = a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 0 ]

        piv = partition(list_,left,right)
        #If items in the left of the pivot push them to the stack
        if piv-1 > left:            
            a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 0 ] = left
            a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 1 ] = piv-1
            i_stack_pos+=1
        if piv+1 < right:
            a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 0 ] = piv+1
            a_temp_stack[ i_stack_pos, 1 ] = right
            i_stack_pos+=1

@nb.autojit( nopython=True )
def partition(list_, left, right):
    """
    Partition method
    """
    #Pivot first element in the array
    piv = list_[left]
    i = left + 1
    j = right

    while 1:
        while i <= j  and list_[i] <= piv:
            i +=1
        while j >= i and list_[j] >= piv:
            j -=1
        if j <= i:
            break
        #Exchange items
        list_[i], list_[j] = list_[j], list_[i]
    #Exchange pivot to the right position
    list_[left], list_[j] = list_[j], list_[left]
    return j
```

Comment: Even with a JIT compiler, it's probably unlikely that you're going to beat an algorithm implemented in [straight C](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c.src). It may also be that your code is falling back to [object mode](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/user/troubleshoot.html#the-compiled-code-is-too-slow).

Comment: You are doing this a `numba` exercise, or because you need quicksort?

Comment: It is not an exercise. I need quicksort in a numba function that I am writing.  The function calls quicksort multiple times. In order to run in nopython mode the function can't use numpy's sort function, so I need to write my own.

Comment: An alternative that works in the simple test case I tried to to put the stuff before and afterwards the call to np.sort in pointless loops (`for ignore_me in range(1):`). It will JIT the loops in nopython mode and there will presumably just be a small overhead for coming in and out of nopython mode. Keep the final return statement outside the loop though.

Comment: You could also use function calls (to functions jit'd with nopython=True) either side of `np.sort` if the silly loops look too silly.

Answer (score 3):

One small suggestion which may help (but as you've rightly been told in the comments to your question, you're going to struggle to beat the pure C implementation):

you want to make sure most of it is done in "nopython" mode (`@jit(nopython=True)`). Add that before your functions and see where it breaks. Also call `inspect_types()` on your function, and see if it's able to identify them correctly.

The one thing in your code that stands out as likely to be forcing it into object mode (as opposed to nopython mode) is the allocation of a numpy array. Although numba can compile loops separately in nopython mode I don't know if it can do that for while-loops. Calling `inspect_types` will tell you.

My usual workround for creating numpy arrays while ensuring the rest is in nopython mode is to create a wrapper function.

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True) # make sure it can be done in nopython mode
def _quick_sort_impl(list_,output_array):
   ...most of your code goes here...

@nb.jit
def quick_sort(list_):
   # this code won't compile in nopython mode, but it's
   # short and isolated
   max_depth = 1000
   a_temp_stack = np.ndarray( ( max_depth, 2), dtype=np.int32 )
   _quick_sort_impl(list_,a_temp_stack)
```

Comment: So... a quick test suggests it's doing your while loop in nopython mode, so my "improvement" makes no measurable difference. The only other thing I can see is that it ends up compiling (and having to choose between) 4 different versions of `partion` (based on the type of integer of `left` and `right`). I can't believe that will help too much though.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you don't force the `nopython` mode you have high chances of getting no performance improvement. Citing from [the docs about `nopython` mode](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/glossary.html#term-nopython-mode):

> [`nopython`] mode produces the highest performance code, but requires that the native types of all values in the function can be inferred, and that no new objects are allocated

Therefore your `np.ndarray` call is triggering object mode and hence slowing down the code. Try to allocate the work array from outside the function, like:

```
def quick_sort(list_):

    max_depth = 1000
    temp_stack_ = np.array( ( max_depth, 2), dtype=np.int32 )

    _quick_sort(list_, temp_stack_)

...

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def _quick_sort(list_, temp_stack_):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, numba has implemented both the general `sorted` function and a numpy-array `.sort()` method as of (I think) version 0.22. Hooray!

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#built-in-functions
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#other-methods